# How to run a hook action when header load in wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, hook

Am woking on an error plugin.
I want to generate some error or success msgs when header loads in WordPress blog site.

like as:

```
if(is header load)
{
  //run a action hook here
  //print success or error msgs through hook function
}
```

suggest a hook action to display msgs when header load.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below code might help. You can put this code in the functions.php in your theme folder.

```
                function load_me_on_header()
            {
               // do something here ... like show error message.
            }

            add_action('wp_head','load_me_on_header');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the add_filter() function the same way.  Filters are more suiteble when content processing is invold.