# Wordpress Plugin Dev: Possible to hook after HEAD and before BODY tags?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook, flush

I'm developing a plugin for myself that has the option of enabling using PHP's flush() function.

The problem is that while every aspect has gone well, I can't find how too have this option run after the closing of `</head>` and before the opening of `<body>`.

So ideally it would run like this:

```
if (isset($options['run_flush'])) {
  add_action(?,'run_flush()');
}
```

Any pointers? I'm relatively new to plugin development, but I'm hardly stupid about PHP and how to search and I can't for the life of me find the answer.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is an action for the head: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315647/how-to-run-a-hook-action-when-header-load-in-wordpress-blog

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried that already, and it keeps echoing any output directly after the <body> tag, e.g., </head><body> ***hook output*** - which isn't what it's supposed to be doing, but that's why that hook won't work for me.